# How to tell if a domain user is a local admin on the machine

Tags: windows, command-line, administrator

I'd like to know if the user `MYDOMAIN\SomeUser` has local admin rights on the current machine.

I can see if a *local user account* has admin by using:

```
C:\>NET USER Mike
User name                    Mike
Full Name
...
Local Group Memberships      *Administrators
```

However, if I try:

```
C:\>NET USER MYDOMAIN\SomeUser
```

or:

```
C:\>NET USER "MYDOMAIN\SomeUser"
```

I get the standard syntax help screen.

I can check this from the "Computer Management" MMC snap-in, but that takes too long to load and I'd like to quickly do this from the command line.  If someone has a VBS script that'd be fine too.

**Note:** If anyone has better tags for this question, please feel free to add them!

Comment: You do understand that a domain level permission  would override any local permissions you might assign a local profile right?

Comment: @Ramhound Seems like he's concerned with domain users, not local users. He understands how to check a local account, but not how to check if a domain account is a local admin from the command line.

Comment: Correct.  I was just looking for command line shortcuts for things I was already doing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try `net localgroup administrators` instead. If you'd like a PowerShell command to check a specific user, take a look at this [blog post](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/04/02/get-local-admin-group-members-in-a-new-old-way/). I would hope however that there aren't so many local administrators that you can't spot the user in question.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you sir.

Comment: That answer just give local admin membership. It does not "tell if a domain user is a local admin on the machine"

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
C:\>NET USER SomeUser /domain
```

instead of

```
C:\>NET USER MYDOMAIN\SomeUser
```

Comment: Since this question has already has an accepted answer you need to give more detail as to why your method is a more suitable option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command to get all information of the user. it's a powershell command.

```
GPRESULT -Z /USER [username]
```